# How to send PWA push notification to subscribe user and how it send to other device which they allows notiification>??

Tags: asp.net, progressive-web-apps

How we can send PWA push notification to other device if they allow notification for that site using ASP.net.

Comment: You cannot. Notifications are allowed in the browser ONLY on the device where the user said YES. That yes, does not apply to other devices and browsers the user has.